# Unable to download the file via Google Drive API using Ruby

Tags: ruby, google-drive-api

Is it possible now to use Google Drive API without oauth authentication?

Basically what I need is download the file from my google drive. I created a service account and shared the file to it, then used google-api-ruby-client library.

The code looks this way:

```
require 'google/apis/drive_v3'
drive = Google::Apis::DriveV3::DriveService.new
scope = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'
drive.authorization = Google::Auth::ServiceAccountCredentials.make_creds(
  json_key_io: File.open('~/service-account.json'),
  scope: scope)

# Download a file
drive.get_file('fileID', download_dest: '/tmp/downloaded-test.txt')
```

It worked well a couple of months ago, but now it always gives 403 error.
Did they make any API changes recently?

UPD:

The strange thing is that I can see the file using files.list method, but when trying to download using get_file I'm getting 403 error - #<Google::Apis::ClientError: Invalid request status_code: 403...

```
result = drive.list_files(q: "", page_size: 100, page_token: nil, fields: 'files(id,name),next_page_token')
result.files.each { |file| puts "#{file.id}, #{file.name}" }
```

Comment: If this is using OAuth, it's possible your token expired.

Comment: I want to do without Oauth, using service account from server to server

Comment: 403 means forbidden I would check the sharing on the file

Comment: I shared to the user from my json file using Editor role. I can list files but unable to download